# show home page through tomcat without changing url

Tags: apache, tomcat, request, forwarding

I have tomcat running behind Apache. I also have Spring security to handle authorization and authrntication and Struts 2 as my web layer framewok.

Here is my requirement:
1) I want to have a home page which shows some data which is dynamic(like categories) which has to be fetched from database and rendered dynamically.
2) I want to display above page when I hit "mysite.com" in address bar without changing the URL ie. browser address bar must show "mysite.com only.

I could have easily kept this home page as index.html on my virtual host's documentroot location. However I cannot do this as some content is generated dynamically.

Another option is to keep this on tomcat and ask apache to forward the request to tomcat. however this changes the URL on my address bar.

How can I handle this? Can ForwardDirectories option in JK_MOD be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now Lets say I have a webapp "mysite" running on tomcat which is behind apache. This mysite webapp has a domain name "mysite.com". 
When I hit "mysite.com" it must return a home page with dynamic content. So I add this as index.jsp in webapps/mysite/ directory.

Follwing is the virtual host I wrote for mysite app:

```
      <VirtualHost *:86>
            ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
            DocumentRoot "D:/var/www/html/mysite"
            ServerName mysite.com
            ServerAlias www.mysite.com
            ErrorLog "logs/mysite-error.log"
            CustomLog "logs/mysite-access.log" common

        <Directory "D:/var/www/html/mysite">
                  #
                  # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
                  # or any combination of:
                  #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI                                              
                  #MultiViews
                  # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
                  # doesn't give it to you.
                  #
                  # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
                  # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
                  # for more information.
                  #
                  Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks

                  #
                  # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess  files.
                  # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
                  #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
                  #
                    AllowOverride None

                  #
                  # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
                  #
                 Require all denied
             Require local granted
           </Directory>
       JkMount /mysite/* localtomcat
       ProxyRequests Off
       ProxyPreserveHost On

       ProxyPass /mysite/  !
       ProxyPass /  http://localhost:8080/mysite/
       ProxyPassReverse /  http://localhost:8080/mysite/

          </VirtualHost>
```

So, Here are my questions on above implementation :
 1)What I have done is mixing the JKMount of mod_jk and proxypass of mod_proxy.Even though 
   this works how standard it is 
 2)Does it have any serious side effects?
 3)What could be alternative solution?

Comment: Yes and sorry for that. it is because I have successfully implemented the thing and its running fine in production. Still I would like to know if its the good approach and if there are any pitfalls in it. Comments from an expert like you will make it a full fledged answer instead of an half baked question and answer.

Comment: Your configuration looks fine, though I have no idea why you'd bother using different protocols to connect to different Tomcat backends.

Answer (score 0):

To serve dynamic content from Tomcat to a specific domain do the following:

1. Create a virtual host on your apache web server that handles "mysite.com".
2. Map the whole content of your virtual host to Tomcat through mod_jk:

   ```
   JkMount /      tomcatsJVMRouteName
   JkMount /*     tomcatsJVMRouteName
   ```
3. Create another host in your Tomcats server.xml that handles "mysite.com".
4. Deploy your application as default application (webapps/ROOT-directory).

Comment: Is it a good idea to Deploy  application as default application (webapps/ROOT-directory)? I heard that it is discouraged by tomcat guys. Is there any other way to do this

Comment: Also this wouldn;t work as I have multiple applications running in my tomcat with the same requirement as stated in my question

Comment: You can create different hosts for different applications running from different webapp directories.

Comment: @Stefen: So you mean to say I should deploy every application in its own appbase right and make it default application in that appbase directory?

Comment: Yes, I did set up such an environment yet and it worked well. The thing with deploying apps in ROOT is that if a url redirection fails it might endup in the ROOT app and might cause a 404 or something else. If there is only one application in that webapps dir that cannot happen. Give it a try.

Comment: @Stefen: I played with it for a while and have come up with much simpler solution though I don't know whether its a good standard solution without any serious side effects. Please find my answer below adding it as an answer as it contains a code example that worked for me